# Directory permissions under /var/lib/kubelet/pods

Tags: security, kubernetes, kubelet

A random 0 byte file is created when we deploy a deployment or daemon-set:

```sh
ls -lart /var/lib/kubelet/pods
0666 *container id*/containers/*container name*/*random file name*
```

Might you be able to provide more information on this file? How may we direct kubernetes to create this file with 0644 or 0640? is there a flag we may pass to kubelet for this?

It is showing up in our security scans as less secure.

This is in version 1.12

I haven't tried anything yet - I just had a security scan on my nodes and am looking for more information and how to prevent this from showing up.

```sh
ls -lart /var/lib/kubelet/pods
0666 *container id*/containers/*container name*/*random file name*
```

All I want is to get around this vulnerability by either fixing it with custom code or an update or by explaining why it has to remain 0666.

Answer (score 0):

Before container is started on a node, the kubelet creates a directory for that Pod on the host system `/var/lib/kubelet/pods/`

I cannot say exactly what is the necessity of those files, because `lsof`doesn't show anything, but my assumptions is that it is used as a mounted volumes in a **pause** container

The only place where permissions are set for this directory is [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/367f13537232bef4ad23b5bb4ecdd090ceb25f33/cluster/get-kube-local.sh#L95)

```
--volume=/var/lib/kubelet/:/var/lib/kubelet:rw \
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

as from my docker inspect investigation

the folder

```
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/
```

is used  to BIND some folders from
host filesystem inside some containers.
to be more specific inside containers that belongs to STATIC pods

suppose we have a pod

```
coredns-f9fd979d6-6h9dc
```

then we have corresponding docker container

```
 k8s_kube-flannel_kube-flannel-ds-pgqq2_kube-system_e3c9e9dc-058a-4871-ae1c-2aa5b9a7fa36_6
```

if we make docker inspect of the container we will see

```
"HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/run/flannel:/run/flannel",
                "/var/lib/kubelet/pods/e3c9e9dc-058a-4871-ae1c-2aa5b9a7fa36/volumes/kubernetes.io~configmap/flannel-cfg:/etc/kube-flannel/:ro",
                "/var/lib/kubelet/pods/e3c9e9dc-058a-4871-ae1c-2aa5b9a7fa36/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/flannel-token-2vbzc:/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount:ro",
```